# Can Query.jl in Julia create rows from arrays of varying size?

Tags: arrays, dataframe, julia

I am wondering how to use Query.jl to extract values from an array in a dataframe and turn them into separate rows.

Background: I have used TextAnalysis.jl to tokenize some text and would like to have a dataframe with one row per token for the subsequent processing. @map got me that far, but despite various attempts with @mapmany I have not been able to get to a solution. Maybe @mapmany is the wrong choice here.

```
example = DataFrame(line = 1:4, text = [["First", "line"], ["Then", "number", "two"], ["And", "numero", "tres"], ["The", "End"]])
```

How do I get a result like this:

```
line | word
-----------------
1    | First
1    | line
2    | Then
…    | …
3    | tres
4    | The
4    | End
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DataFrames.flatten`](https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/latest/lib/functions/#DataFrames.flatten) should do what you want:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> example = DataFrame(line = 1:4, text = [["First", "line"], ["Then", "number", "two"], ["And", "numero", "tres"], ["The", "End"]])
4×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ line  │ text                      │
│     │ Int64 │ Array{String,1}           │
├─────┼───────┼───────────────────────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ ["First", "line"]         │
│ 2   │ 2     │ ["Then", "number", "two"] │
│ 3   │ 3     │ ["And", "numero", "tres"] │
│ 4   │ 4     │ ["The", "End"]            │

julia> flatten(example, :text)
10×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ line  │ text   │
│     │ Int64 │ String │
├─────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ First  │
│ 2   │ 1     │ line   │
│ 3   │ 2     │ Then   │
│ 4   │ 2     │ number │
│ 5   │ 2     │ two    │
│ 6   │ 3     │ And    │
│ 7   │ 3     │ numero │
│ 8   │ 3     │ tres   │
│ 9   │ 4     │ The    │
│ 10  │ 4     │ End    │
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually map this out using repeat and some array manipulations

```
lines = [...]
flat_lines = vcat(lines...)
line_no = repeat(1:4, inner=2)
df = DataFrame(line=line_no, word=flat_lines)
```